# how to open presenter in browser address?

Tags: nette

1. I have Homepage presenter i want to view what inside it in homepage. how can i open it in webaddress ? i already try to open it 
   with this http://localhost/sandbox/www/homepage/action it wont open
2. What the different between method action and render.. forexample i have this two method…
   actionOut() and renderOut() in the Homepage Presenter when i route it it nette cannot make any different between two..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This depends on your routing. The default one allows you to access all presenters by pattern `<module>.<presenter>/<action>`. So the question is if the Homepage presenter is in any module, what's the routing, ... You can take a look at debugbar, where you can find a routing panel that may help you understand which route was matched. Also, you didn't specify, what is the exact error.
2. I encourage you take a look at the [lifecycle of the Presenter](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.3/presenters#toc-life-cycle-of-presenter). Basically, the action method is run always, even if you redirect in a signal method. The render method is run only when the presenter is going to render the current action. The action method should take care of getting the primary resource and "storing" it to the presenter's property, not the template! The render method takes the resource and pushes it to the template. If the resource method is not available, you should call `$this->error()` in your action method.